# SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN after installing certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I use `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` Docker image for generate my all subdomaine with SSL certificate.

For my first subdomain it work nice, but for my seconde, i've this error on my browser :

```
SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

secondSubDomain.my-site.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for firstSubDomaine.my-site.com.
```

I don't undetstand why, because i see all `.chain.pem` and `.crt` by sub-domain on the `certs` folder :/

My docker-compose file for my secondSubDomain :

```
version: "3"

services:
  jackett:
    image: linuxserver/jackett
    container_name: jackett
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=jackett.${SITE_URL}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=9117
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=jackett.${SITE_URL}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${MAILER_DEFAUT_SENDER_ADDRESS}
    volumes:
      - ${MOUNT_POINT}/jackett/config:/config
      - ${MOUNT_POINT}/jackett/downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - "9117:9117"
    expose:
      - 9117

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: nginx-proxy
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: It looks like you're generating two certificates for the same URL. You're trying to execute `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` container for these two URL.
You should use the same image for two containers. First container using url **firstSubDomaine.my-site.com** and second docker container using **secondSubDomain.my-site.com**

Comment: The `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` container is separated from my 2 app. You think i need to add for all app and not only 1 container for all ?

Comment: This is one possibility, maybe not the only one. You can use `docker-compose scale` to create more containers with the same service from the same image. So, it looks that can solve it to you.

Comment: Actualy i've only one `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` container for generate my all SSL certs. In the documentation of this container, i see good practice. But i dont' understand why it's work only for the first subdomain :/

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have same issues.

Comment: Nop :( if you have solution .. :)